# Getting Black Bars in iphone 6 Flash Movie?

Tags: ios, iphone, air, adobe, flash-cs6

I'm working on Flash cs6, Adobe AIR18 and am having a resolution problem displaying flash video. My code:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
stage.align     = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

On iPads my videos display full screen, but on iphone 6 and 6+ I'm getting black bars left and right.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it might be because you are not including the necessary iPhone 6 and 6+ Default images. If these are not included in your package the app will revert to displaying a 4:3 ratio stage. This is an iOS thing.

Take a look here for the correct naming formats and sizes for the Default images.

http://blog.tomasmahrik.com/list-of-properties-sizes-for-application-icons-launch-images-screenshots-video-previews-for-ios-air-apps/